# Is it possibe to have multiple kerberos tickets on same machine?

Tags: kerberos

I have a use case where I need to connect to 2 different DBS using 2 different accounts. And I am using Kerberos for authentication.

Is it possible to create multiple Kerberos tickets on same machine?
kinit account1@DOMAIN.COM (first ticket)
kinit account2@DOMAIN.COM (second ticket)
Whenever I do klist, I only see most recent ticket created. It doesn't show all the tickets.

Next, I have a job that needs to first use ticket for account1 (for connection to DB1) and then use ticket for account2 (for DB2).
Is that possible? How do I tell in DB connection what ticket to use?

Comment: Serious apps should be able to create their own private Kerberos ticket and store it in-memory (based on a keytab file or interactive prompt for password). Less serious apps use the ticket cache, as defined by **`KRB5CCNAME`** env var / failing that by an entry on `krb5.conf` / failing that by the hard-coded default for your OS.

Comment: Does it matter what user is used to create the keytab file - service account, root or app specific account? I have a python script on VM that uses a kerberos ticket to login to a system. When i run that script from terminal as a service account user, it can't authenticate into the app that I am trying to access. But when I run the same script from an app (app uses a specific user ), it is able to authenticate. So the difference is the user who is running the python script.

Comment: Sure. Linux has been using POSIX access privileges for files -- e.g. `u=rw,g=r,o=` -- for about 50 years... and more recently POSIX ACLs for more granular access control (and automatic inheritance of privileges for new files). Kerberos has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I have 2 keytabs on same VM for 2 systems I need to authenticate to
`sudo kinit myid@REALM -k -t myid.keytab` - for key management server
`sudo kinit svc-account@REALM -k -t svc-account.keytab` - for database
And I noticed, whenever I execute above a file get created in `/tmp/krb5cc_0` but it gets overwritten by second kinit. That means I can only authenticate to one system at a time.  How to get around that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming MIT Kerberos and linking to those docs.

Try `klist -A` to show all tickets in the ticket cache.  If there is only one try switching your ccache type to `DIR` as described [here](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/basic/ccache_def.html#ccache-types):

> DIR points to the storage location of the collection of the credential caches in FILE: format. It is most useful when dealing with multiple Kerberos realms and KDCs. For release 1.10 the directory must already exist. In post-1.10 releases the requirement is for parent directory to exist and the current process must have permissions to create the directory if it does not exist. See Collections of caches for details. New in release 1.10. The following residual forms are supported:
>
> ```
> DIR:dirname
> DIR::dirpath/filename - a single cache within the directory
> ```
>
> Switching to a ccache of the latter type causes it to become the primary for the directory.

You do this by specifying the default ccache name as `DIR:/path/to/cache` on one of the ways described [here](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/basic/ccache_def.html#default-ccache-name).

> The default credential cache name is determined by the following, in descending order of priority:
>
> ```
> The KRB5CCNAME environment variable. For example, KRB5CCNAME=DIR:/mydir/.
> The default_ccache_name profile variable in [libdefaults].
> The hardcoded default, DEFCCNAME.
> ```